# Mongodb $near after $lookup

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework, database

How can i make a query of services using $near if the location coordinates are in another collection?

$lookup, $near

I have 2 collections, one is for the users and another is for services.
The user collection is:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("570557d4094a4514fc1291d6"), "fullname" : "John Doe",
"position" : {
    "street" : "Piazza Santa Maria",
    "city" : "Busto",
    "country" : "Italy",
    "zip_code" : "21052",
    "address" : "Piazza Santa Maria, 21052 Busto, Province of Varese, Italy",
    "location" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [ 
            8.8502715, 
            45.6114064
        ]
    },
    "country_code" : "IT",
    "state" : "Lombardy",
    "province" : "Province of Varese"
 }
}
```

}

The service collection is:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("960557d4094a4514fc1291a7"), 
author_id : ObjectId("570557d4094a4514fc1291d6"), title:"Software developer"}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("960557d4094a4514fc1291a7"), 
author_id : ObjectId("570557d4094a4514fc1291d6"), title:"App developer"}
```

I want to find all documents in service collection based on author location.

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost, you need to satisfy couple of requirements of MongoDB location based queries.

1. Create a `2dsphere` index on `users` collection
2. `$geoNear` stage should be first stage in aggregation pipeline.

**Example:**

```
db.users.aggregate([
  {
    $geoNear: {
      near: {type: "Point", coordinates: [ 8.840 , 45.6114060 ]},
      distanceField: "dist.calculated",
      maxDistance:1000,
      spherical: true
  }},
  {
    $lookup: {
      from:"services", localField:"_id", foreignField:"author_id", as: "services"
  }}
])
```

Here we are trying to find documents falling with in 1000 meters range. In this case document with location `[8.8502715, 45.6114064]`

**Output**:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("570557d4094a4514fc1291d6"), 
    "fullname" : "John Doe", 
    "position" : {
        "street" : "Piazza Santa Maria", 
        "city" : "Busto", 
        "country" : "Italy", 
        "zip_code" : "21052", 
        "address" : "Piazza Santa Maria, 21052 Busto, Province of Varese, Italy", 
        "location" : {
            "type" : "Point", 
            "coordinates" : [
                8.8502715, 
                45.6114064
            ]
        }, 
        "country_code" : "IT", 
        "state" : "Lombardy", 
        "province" : "Province of Varese"
    }, 
    "dist" : {
        "calculated" : 799.8404739526889
    }, 
    "services" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("960557d4094a4514fc1291a7"), 
            "author_id" : ObjectId("570557d4094a4514fc1291d6"), 
            "title" : "Software developer"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("580d499eb22270301913d677"), 
            "author_id" : ObjectId("570557d4094a4514fc1291d6"), 
            "title" : "Software developer"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("580d499eb22270301913d678"), 
            "author_id" : ObjectId("570557d4094a4514fc1291d6"), 
            "title" : "App developer"
        }
    ]
}
```

If we plot both documents on google map for verification, we'll get

[image: Google map image]

As you can see on image, our document locations are roughly 800 meters apart so with in 1000 meters range as specified in query. See on [Goole map](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/'45.6114060,8.840'/45.6114064,8.8502715/@45.6117695,8.8407343,16z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m6!4m5!1m3!2m2!1d8.84!2d45.611406!1m0)

Comment: I think OP wants to find services in range for an author. Your answer tries to find the authors in range.

Comment: @Veeram. I see your point, thanks for pointing out. Just updated solution

Comment: OP wants to lookup first and then near in the collection . So you may want to aggregate on services collection, and then look up authors collection for location coordinates.

Comment: Nop. This will not work. You are missing location field in services collection which is whole point of this question. Location. Asked queries will not work without proper index.

Comment: Hi @Saleem, I want to find services based on author location.

Comment: @Harald services are being returned as part of output. However, if you want to see just services array, append $project stage to aggregation pipeline.

Comment: @Saleem the reason that i want services first is that i want to find the services that match a title first, there can be more than 1 services, after i need the service which author location is near my location.

Comment: Well, nothing is stopping finding more than one services.  You can always filter out services based on title. Please read requirements of using location based constructs in mongodb.

Comment: @Saleem so as I understand, using aggregation to find all services and lookup for user collection is not possible to make a query to user collection?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126533/discussion-between-saleem-and-harald).